# Lambda - select all items which meets ALL selected values in e.g. checkboxlist

Tags: linq, model-view-controller, lambda

I have a list of categories - looped out in a list of checkboxes. And I have some products belonging to one OR multiple of the categories. If the user select 3 of the categories, I need a lambda-expression which can **output only the products which meets ALL the selected categories** - and not the products which only meets one or two of the categories.

Let's say I have the following products:

- A ... belonging category 1, 2 and 4
- B ... belonging category 2
- C ... belonging category 3 and 4
- D ... belonging category 2 and 4

If the user **select category 2 and 4** in the list of checkboxes - the output (via a lambda-expression) should only be **product A and D**.

I hope it makes sense. It's probably quite easy, but I can not figure it out - have been looking for a solution for a few hours now. Unsuccessfully.

UPDATE!
Thanks to Deepak Mishra (my friend in need - I struggled to extract a code example, and Deepak Mishra made one for me - thank you very much) I now can update with this principle code example:

Class:

```
public class Products
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
}
```

Dummy data:

```
List<Products> ProdList = new List<Products>();//code that add Product and Category in list
ProdList.Add(new Products() { ProductName = "A", Category = 1 });//A ... belonging category 1, 2 and 4
ProdList.Add(new Products() { ProductName = "A", Category = 2 });//A ... belonging category 1, 2 and 4
ProdList.Add(new Products() { ProductName = "A", Category = 4 });//A ... belonging category 1, 2 and 4
ProdList.Add(new Products() { ProductName = "B", Category = 2 });//B ... belonging category 2
ProdList.Add(new Products() { ProductName = "C", Category = 3 });//C ... belonging category 3 and 4
ProdList.Add(new Products() { ProductName = "C", Category = 4 });//C ... belonging category 3 and 4
ProdList.Add(new Products() { ProductName = "D", Category = 2 });//D ... belonging category 2 and 4
ProdList.Add(new Products() { ProductName = "D", Category = 4 });//D ... belonging category 2 and 4

List<int> userInput = new List<int>() { 2, 4 };//user select category 2 and 4 in the list of checkboxes
```

UPDATE:

This expression do the job - but unfortunately it returns ALL products beloning category 2 OR 4. And not what I want: Only products belonging both category 2 AND 4:

```
var Products = ProdList.Where(p => userInput.Contains(p.Category)).ToList();
```

Comment: If you are asking for help than at least provide the the MVC so people dont have to start from scratch just to show you the solution.

Comment: You need to create some data structures (aka classes)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question asked by you is updated. You need to use below code-

> //Group data from prodlist

```
  var prodG = ProdList.GroupBy(m => m.ProductName).Select(g => new
        {
            ProductName = g.Key,
            data = g.Select(prod => new
            {
                prod.ProductName,
                prod.Category
            })
        }).ToList();
```

> //select data from grouped prod list

```
  var Products = prodG.Where(pg => userInput.All(c => pg.data.Where(m => m.ProductName == pg.ProductName)
            .Select(m => m.Category)
            .ToList().Contains(c)))
            .Select(p => p.ProductName)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your product class as-

```
public class Products
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public List<int> Category { get; set; }
}
```

Below code will insert dummy data-

```
List<Products> ProdList = new List<Products>();//code that add Product and Category in list
ProdList.Add(new Products() { ProductName = "A", Category = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 4 } });//A ... belonging category 1, 2 and 4
ProdList.Add(new Products() { ProductName = "B", Category = new List<int>() { 2 } });//B ... belonging category 2
ProdList.Add(new Products() { ProductName = "C", Category = new List<int>() { 3, 4 } });//C ... belonging category 3 and 4
ProdList.Add(new Products() { ProductName = "D", Category = new List<int>() { 2, 4 } });//D ... belonging category 2 and 4
List<int> userInput = new List<int>() { 2, 4 };//user select category 2 and 4 in the list of checkboxes
```

Final landa expression to select products or the output (via a lambda-expression) -

```
 var Products = ProdList.Where(p => userInput.All(c => p.Category.Contains(c))).Select(p => p.ProductName).ToList();
```

Comment: Deepak Mishra ... thanks a lot for the code example. I I struggled a hard fight to extract my own code example for the question.

Comment: Your suggestion is almost there ... except that I have a slightly different class structure for the category (int not list of int) as shown in my update example (yours with a little correction - my mistake, sorry). This little correction gives an error since it is not possible to use p.Category.Contains(c) when the category is not a list. Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: I owe it to explain that in the larger setup it is about many-to-many ... product - relationship table - category. But the problem can be isolated to relationship table (Products in the example) - category ... the rest should be a walk in the park.

Comment: In the original (older) solution with SQL, I solved the problem by counting the number of rows. If the user selected 3 categories - products  that were represented less than 3 times in the "result-set", was dropped. Or in other words - only products, represented just as many times as selected categories, was selected for the final result-set. But is it possible to do something similar with lambda? Count the number of product-representation and drop the products that are represented to few times? Or are there other and more clever options with lambda/Linq?

Comment: It works perfectly. @Deepak ... thank you very much. You are my hero :-)